# maven war copy all files from one place to another

Tags: angularjs, maven, maven-3

Now i am creating simple project using spring and angularJS. So now in default maven web directory webapp i have got  folders app , dist, node_modules and also files package.json, karma.conf.js, Gruntfile etc. My purpose is when i am build my war file all files under dist folder are copy to parent webapp folder, and war does not contain other folders and files such as app, dist, node_modules etc. Below i attach show what shows what I would receive in my war file.

[image]

**Can you show me simple maven configuration ?**